# Xamarin Forms Add to Cart Button Implementation

Tags: c#, woocommerce, xamarin.forms

I am building a shopping application with an add to cart button on the Detail product page, how do I handle the add to cart button such that it adds the product to the shopping cart page or a list I can access on all pages. The product database is accessed via this [WooCommerce API](https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET)

From the product list view, I set the tapped product to the binding context of the product detail page.

```
async void Handle_FlowItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tappedproduct = e.Item as Product;

        var productView = new ProductItemViewPage()
        {
            BindingContext = tappedproduct

        };
        await Navigation.PushAsync(productView);
    }
```

Detail Page

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class ProductItemViewPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProductItemViewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

         protected override void OnAppearing()
        {

        }



        void AddBag_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

           var selectproduct = BindingContext as Product;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with what you're currently doing?  Are you getting an error, or is it not behaving like you want?  Please be more specific about the problem.  Simply asking "how to implement a shopping cart" is far to broad to be meaningfully answered here.

Comment: Hi @Jason when I click the AddBag button nothing happens at the moment, I would like the product to be stored in a session list locally or any other alternative that would provide a similar function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a shopping cart class as a singleton, and access it from both the detail page and the shopping cart page via the class Instance property.

[Here is a link](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) showing how to create a singleton class .

If you have the opportunity to refactor the app, I would recommend using an MVVM pattern using something like FreshMvvm. Then you could implement the shopping cart as a service and inject it into the view models using IOC.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) to an article about MVVM/FreshMvvm

Comment: Could you please explain further please, I am not familiar with Singletons

Comment: I've looked it up and a singleton would not work in this scenario because when a user logs out and another logs in (on the same device) they would have access to the previous users cart or am I wrong?

Comment: depends how you implement singleton. Usually it is in memory, so if you didn't close an app and another user loges in he will have access to old cart but you always can also store user name in cart and clear it if login doesn't match cart's user name or have dictionary "Username-Cart" in your singleton. On another hand you can store the cart in device permanently using Jame's Montemagno plugin.

Comment: As you need to share a shopping cart between different pages, you will have to implement a long running class using either a singleton, a service class or other mechanism (like local storage using James Montemagnos plugin as Yuri suggested). As it is long running it will still be around when the user logs out and another logs in. This means it is up to you to manage the user details attached to the shopping cart. One approach would be to create the shopping cart when a user logs in and clear it when they log out or another user logs in.